# How to quickly identify whether there is any blockage during streaming data processing?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

In the cluster, I create multiple streaming tables together with multiple subscriptions using different topics. But the processing of several subscriptions is obviously delayed. How can I quickly identify whether there is any blockage during streaming data processing?

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB provides a monitoring function `getStreamingStat()`, which can be used for more detailed queries through the following functions:

```
getStreamingStat().subWorkers  //query the subscription status
```

If there is no accumulation in `queueDepth`, it means that the consumption of stream data is not blocked.

```
getStreamingStat().pubConns //the publish connection status
```

If there is no accumulation in `queueDepth`, it means that the distribution of streaming data is not blocked.